# Ubuntu desktop issues/overall systematic issues

Tags: unity, skype, .desktop

I have installed skype on my Ubuntu 14.04.2 version and after I restarted the computer the normal Login window popped up. After typing in the password the desktop was on but the sidebar was missing and none of the functions except ctrl+alt+f1 were working. I tried to re-install unity and desktop but it did not help. I tried advanced start up modes but the result was still the same. I was wondering if I need to re-install the whole system, or is there any other way to fix this problem? And if re-installation is needed, can it be done from USB with the help of Command line?

Comment: What makes you think the problem is related to Skype? Did you do anything else before rebooting? One thing you can try is: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` . If anything gets installed that way, try to reboot again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your proposal, and I got a response: "Unable to locate package desktop". Another thing I have not seen before was a statement when I performed a log in in Command Line: E:/No directory, logging in with HOME, any ideas what that might be? Besides the Guest mode works just fine.

Comment: You seem to have mistyped the command I suggested (the package name is `ubuntu-desktop`). But nevermind, the fact that it works fine when you are in a guest session indicates that something in your $HOME folder has been corrupted, and that the problem lies there. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic but very rough way to get a working user session when something unknown in the $HOME folder has been corrupted. **Consider this as a last resort if nothing else helps.**

Execute this series of commands:

```
cd /home
sudo mv "$USER" "$USER".bak
sudo mkdir "$USER"
cd
sudo chown "$USER": .
cp -rT /etc/skel/ .
```

Log out and log in again

Copy documents and other stuff of your choice from the old $HOME folder (with the .bak extension) to the new one.

*Edit:*

To fix insufficient permissions in the old $HOME, do this:

```
cd /home
sudo chown -R "$USER": "$USER".bak
```

Comment: Thanks again, your "last resort" let me to log in with my password to my account. Despite that once I want to open USER.bak file, the system tells me: "You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of USER.bak" and only want to extract some of my working files from there. Any last ideas? And thanks again for the help.

Comment: @RemigijusZabiela: I edited the answer, and added a couple of commands which hopefully fix the permissions issue. Actually, this might be what caused the login problem to begin with.

Comment: Yes, this thing has helped, the only funny part here is that user.bak file inside is completely empty. I guess everything that I had in there is lost to "cyber" anyway.  Thanks

Comment: @RemigijusZabiela: Sorry to hear that, but it cannot be due to the commands above, since they don't delete anything. Maybe your $HOME had been accidentally emptied before you got here, and maybe that's the reason why you couldn't log in.